# npm doesn't install global modules correct

Tags: macos, node.js, coffeescript, npm

There's a problem with installing my global modules properly.

### My System

- **OS**: OS X Mountain Lion
- **node.js**: 0.10.18 (Package installer)

### Steps to reproduce

**Input**

`npm install coffee -g` *(or any other module)*

**Output**

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coffee
{lots of dependencies}
coffee@0.0.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee
├── node-getopt@0.2.3
├── modular-amd@0.1.2
├── chai@1.7.2 (assertion-error@1.0.0)
├── mocha@1.11.0 (growl@1.7.0, debug@0.7.2, commander@0.6.1, diff@1.0.2, mkdirp@0.3.5, ms@0.3.0, jade@0.26.3, glob@3.2.1)
├── express@3.2.6 (methods@0.0.1, fresh@0.1.0, range-parser@0.0.4, cookie-signature@1.0.1, buffer-crc32@0.2.1, cookie@0.1.0, debug@0.7.2, commander@0.6.1, mkdirp@0.3.4, send@0.1.0, connect@2.7.11)
├── sinon@1.7.3 (buster-format@0.5.6)
└── sinon-chai@2.4.0
```

**Input**

`coffee`

**Output**

```
-bash: coffee: command not found
```

### Other information

- **`npm config get prefix`**: `/usr/local`
- **Read/Write access für `/usr/local`**: Yes
- **`$PATH`**: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin`
- **`/usr/local/share/npm` exists**: No
- **`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee` exists**: Yes
- **`/usr/local/bin/coffee` exists**: No

What else can I do?

I **won't** add the direct link to coffee to my `$PATH`-variable, because that's not my job, that's the job of `npm`! Really, why should I use npm when I could do it by myself? I read that answer like 100 times and I have no words for this, which aren't against the rules on SO.

Comment: How did you install node.js? from package? via homebrew?

Comment: I used the package from nodejs.org

Comment: npm should be creating a symlink to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee/bin/coffee at /usr/local/bin/coffee.  Something is wrong if it doesn't do that...

Comment: Yes, I know. I already looked if the permissions are wrong, but both the root and my user have read+write access.

Comment: I just figured out that this problem only occurs with coffee and grunt. I tried to install less and the symlink was added correct.

Comment: Well, if I'm too stupid to mix up 'coffee' and 'coffee-script' and 'grunt' and 'grunt-cli' everything is lost. I gonna look for a new job. Thank you.

Comment: wow user vs patience , 0-1 , relax..

Comment: what does the output of `which coffee` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to install CoffeeScript globally (as one of the tags suggests), you shall install **coffee-script** (not [coffee](https://npmjs.org/package/coffee)).
Additionally, sudo is required for installing global module on the Mac.

Command:

> sudo npm install coffee-script -g

**Input**

```
% coffee
```

**Output**

```
coffee>
```

Comment: I waited 3 weeks for someone, who reads the comments, sees there is no answer and creates one. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I tried to install `grunt` in various ways (and using sudo) and was told it went into: `~/local/lib/node_modules/grunt`, but there's nothing in bin and I get command-not-found as a result.

Comment: If you want to install grunt executable, remember to install `grunt-cli` (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cli) not `grunt`